# How to use QTextStream::readLine function?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to read values from a text file using the Qt code given below.

```
int ReadFromFile(QString fileName)
{
   QFile file(fileName);
   if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
      return 1;

   QTextStream in(&file);
   while (!in.atEnd())
   {
      QString line = in.readLine(1); //read one line at a time
      QStringList lstLine = line.split(",");
   }
   file.close();
   return 0;
}
```

The content of the text file is as follows:

```
1,0.173648178  
2,0.342020143  
3,0.5  
4,0.64278761  
5,0.766044443  
6,0.866025404
```

However readLine always returns one character at a time but my intention is to read one line at a time and to split each line to get the individual comma seperated values.

Am I missing something basic here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You're passing 1 for the `maxlen` parameter, which means to limit the line length to only 1 character. Try it without supplying anything for `maxlen`.

Comment: when i try that way, readLine returns the contents of more than one line!

Comment: Hmm, I can't duplicate that. Using the data you supplied, readLine() works fine for me.

Comment: The problem was that the lines were incorreclty terminated by "\r", the lines did not have has correct trailing end-of-line characters "\r\n"

Answer (score 1):

remove zero from your code and try..

```
   QTextStream in(&file);
   while (!in.atEnd())
   {
      QString line = in.readLine(); //read one line at a time
      QStringList lstLine = line.split(",");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be an old post but it looks like you are overwriting your lstLine variable during each iteration.

This one:

```
QStringList lstLine = line.split(",");
```

Change to

```
int ReadFromFile(QString fileName)
{
   QStringList lstLine;
   QFile file(fileName);
   if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
      return 1;
   QTextStream in(&file);
   while (!in.atEnd())
   {
      QString line = in.readLine(); //specifying number = # of characters
      lstLine.append( line.split(",") );
   }
   file.close();
   return 0;
}
```