# Use QTextStream to read the first line in a string

Tags: python, qt, readline, pyqt5, qtextstream

How can I use `QTextStream` to read the first line in a string (read from a file before)?

```
streamin = QTextStream(str)
line = streamin.readLine()
```

It seems that this code doesn't work.

Comment: add some context (more code), you will not meet oracle here which is able to say what did you do wrong.

Comment: Again, like Marek suggested, please correct your syntax and post real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [QTextStream](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qtextstream.html) class does not accept python strings directly. For PyQt5, you must convert the string to a [QByteArray](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qbytearray.html) first:

```
>>> s = """\
... First Line
... Second Line
... Third Line
... """
>>> ba = QtCore.QByteArray(s.encode('utf-8'))
>>> ts = QtCore.QTextStream(ba)
>>> ts.setCodec('utf-8')
>>> ts.readLine()
'First Line'
```

Comment: accepted answer proofs that you should write that `str` is python string. Anyway this answer is a bit to complicated, [see this page](http://www.commandprompt.com/community/pyqt/x2068). So to fix you code this should be enough: `streamin = QTextStream(QString(str))`

Comment: @MarekR. You missed that the OP is using PyQt5. There is no QString in PyQt5, so only a QIODevice or QByteArray can be passed to the QTextStream constructor. Of course, your suggestion would work with PyQt4. Personally, I would avoid all the complications and use python's [io](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#) module for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm basically going to post a snippet of code from the [Qt Documentation Site](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html).

Better yet... here's something from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942651/how-to-use-qtextstreamreadline-function) as well.

```
// Instead of feeding in stdin, you can feed in QFile - i.e. QIODevice
QFile file("myfile");
// ... open file etc etc
QTextStream stream(&file);
QString line;
line = stream.readLine();
```

Comment: It's good,but I want to get the first line from a string not a file.